# Ajax POST inside a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, ajax, loops, foreach, .post

I'm using $.post for posting some data, for eg, a variable, company name to a controller method, inside a php foreach loop. In the controller I echo back a bargraph that is plotted using the data that is passed.
Now inside the foreach loop I'm dynamically generating an id which will be passed to a certain '' element and I need to plot this bargraph passed back inside that div.
The code I'm using now is posted below:

```
    <?php
        $id=0;
        foreach($customer_companies as $data) {
            $company_name=$data->CompanyName;
            echo '<tr>
                  <script>function show_graph()
            {
                $.post("'.$base.'reports/single_bargraph/'.$company_name.'",      {},function(result){
                       $("#'.$id.'").html(result);
                });
             }                                  
        </script> 
        <td class="tablecntntgry" id="'.$id.'" height="45"> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> show_graph();   </script>                            
        </td>
      </tr>';
?>
```

Suppose, I have implemented pagination for fetching data $customer_companies, and 3 are displayed in page at a time. Now the problem that I face is the graph is not plotted in the id's specified.:( Sometimes, it would be plotted in the correct 3 td's generated but sometimes 2/3 would be plotted in the same td overlapping the other:(
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your approach is not acceptable - you shouldn't be writing inline JS like that. Then you redefine and immediately call every time the `show_graph()` function - no way.

Comment: js function show_graph() is in loop, hence will not work

Comment: there is a reason there are views on earth with mvc. why parse your data for **js / html** in your controller method? just push that data to view and parse it there. change your approach towards working with this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$id` is always zero in your sample.
2. you need to make separate functions `show_graph'.$i.'()` (to be honest you don't need functions at all, put your `$.post` after the table)

---

**Edit:** Your script should looks like this:

```
<?php

echo "<table>";
foreach ($customer_companies as $id => $data) {    
    echo '<tr><td class="tablecntntgry" id="row' . $id . '" height="45"></td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";

// NOTE i open <script> tag after </table> closing tag

echo '<script>';
foreach ($customer_companies as $id => $data) {
    $company_name = $data->CompanyName;
    echo '
    $.post("' . $base . 'reports/single_bargraph/' . $company_name . '", {},function(result){
        $("#row' . $id . '").html(result);
    });                                  
    ';
}
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: OOPS.. There's a if loop inside which the foreach is wrapped and I increment the value of $i there..

Comment: @AnuVenugopal remove functions, put your `$.post` after the table (this may need second loop)

Comment: But if I put the $.post after the table, then how is it possible to pass the company name each time as it is generated in the foreach loop? Also I need the graph plotted for each of the values.

Comment: as suggested by @EXQStudio u will need to have one more foreach loop.
as you are having all the data with you in `$customer_companies` variable, it would't be difficult to iterate through the records again

Comment: As per your suggestions, I have changed the code so that now there is no function calls and also there is another foreach loop after the table tag ends inside which the $.post script is given and the company names are posted. But still the graphs are being plotted in the same column itself instead of their respected id's..:(

Comment: Also when we check the firebug, the responses are coming fine and the id's are generated fine.. But the graphs are not being plotted on the id's as specified in the code.

Comment: @AnuVenugopal split loop into 2 loops: put first loop which will create tables. put second loop after it, which will create $.post requests

Comment: @EXQStudio Yeah, I did like you said only. Like I now have a foreach where the table would be plotted. Then after the table ends, I have another foreach for generating the script for $.post where I pass the values. Still no progress..

Comment: @EXQStudio Thank You once again.. But let me tell you my problem once again, I'm actually doing it the way u told me to.. But its like, if there are three ajax responses, the three would be taking different time.. May be the second one is taking the lowset time, then the third and finally the 2nd, as per the data that is fetched. So the responses will be overridden by the loop so that it wont plot in the corresponding columns.. Can u help me with this one plz?

Comment: @Anu what you mean by "it wont plot in the corresponding columns.." do you want to sort them by response time?

Comment: @EXQStudio What I mean is I need to plot the results in say three td's and I need them in the order I pass the company names. But here the response time for each call would vary and the results would not be received in the order passed. Ie, if there is a loop in which its executing, that will be overridden by the ajax response time and the graphs would not be plotted in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Usually AJAX requests take time to get response. But by the time response arrives to client machine, you have overwritten the function!

I suggest you to put the script tag somewhere before your PHP foreach loop and alter the function to accept two parameters.

1. Company Name
2. result div ID

Answer (score 0):

You really need to rethink your approach here, you are abusing the flexibility of javascript. You are defining the `showGraph()` function multiple times, so which version of the method do you expect javascript to trigger? Probably the first. Separate your js from your php.

```
<?php
        $id=0;
        foreach($customer_companies as $data) {
            $company_name=$data->CompanyName;
            echo '<tr id="'.$data['CompanyName'].'" class="companies"></tr>';
?>

$(function(){
   $('.companies').each(function(){
      $.post("'.$base.'reports/single_bargraph/'.$company_name.'",      {},function(result){
                       $(this).append('<td class="tablecntntgry">'+result+'</td>');
                });
   });
});
```

Comment: if we talk about good practice this is not good practice. what if there is space in company name?

Comment: I'm not writing his entire code for him... I'm pointing him in the right direction with a jumping off point. A space in the ID is far more manageable than multiple declarations of a function.